# TYPO3: Printing variables in HTML5 via Fluid does not work

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using Typo3(6.2)
I have problems showing my typoscript variables in my html5 file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
     ....
        <p>{content_test -> f:format.raw()}</p>
     ....
    </body>   
</html>
```

my typoscript:

```
page = PAGE
page {
 config.doctype = html5
 config.xmlprologue = none

10 = FILE
10.file = index.html  
}

fluidTemplate = FLUIDTEMPLATE
fluidTemplate {
  file = index.html

  variables{
    content_test < styles.content.get
  }
}
```

But I get just this output in my browser "{content_test -> f:format.raw()}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the fluidtemplate in the page

```
page = PAGE
page {
    config.doctype = html5
    config.xmlprologue = none

    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        file = index.html

        variables{
            content_test < styles.content.get
        }
    }
}
```